# Require 3rd party payment APIs (like Venmo, Coinbase, or Dwolla) to send authentication info when making a POST request to my Rails URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, authentication

I have a url `buy_product_url` which allows users to buy a virtual product on my site.  The user can pay for product using a variety of payment services, including those listed in the title.  The user pays the appropriate amount through the 3rd party site and then 3rd party site the sends my `buy_product_url` a POST request validating that the purchase was made.

A malicious user could send a POST request to the same url and gain the virtual product without paying.

I'd like to set up some kind of authentication system for POST requests to that URL (for example, http authentication or an access token) and then give these credentials to the 3rd party payment service.  The 3rd party can then send these credentials back to me when a valid purchase is made and if the credentials are not sent, my app should return an error.

Is this possible?  If so, how do I set it up?  Is it only possible for certain payment services?  If so, which ones?

Comment: Don't all these services have a nonce in their API that they pass through and that you are supposed to check to prevent these kind of replay attacks?

Comment: They do.  In that case, how do I disallow POST requests made that don't come from these services?

Comment: You check the nonce. If it's good, it's a valid request. No one else knows or can guess the nonce (if you create it properly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You check the nonce. If it's good, it's a valid request. No one else knows or can guess the nonce (if you create it properly). –  Thilo Sep 8 '13 at 6:26"